# How to make the viewport of an SVG image square, without resizing its contents?

Tags: python, svg, imagemagick, inkscape

I have an SVG image (lets say a simple icon) which has following content:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M436 160c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20V48c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v416c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h320c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48v-48h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20zm-74 304H54a6 6 0 0 1-6-6V54a6 6 0 0 1 6-6h308a6 6 0 0 1 6 6v404a6 6 0 0 1-6 6zM128 208c0-44.183 35.817-80 80-80s80 35.817 80 80-35.817 80-80 80-80-35.817-80-80zm208 133.477V360c0 13.255-10.745 24-24 24H104c-13.255 0-24-10.745-24-24v-18.523c0-22.026 14.99-41.225 36.358-46.567l35.657-8.914c29.101 20.932 74.509 26.945 111.97 0l35.657 8.914C321.01 300.252 336 319.452 336 341.477z"/></svg>
```

The viewbox is not square (448!=512) I need to make the shorter edge equal to the longer one, in a way that its content does not loose their original ratio (=> don't stretch), and they need to get at the exact center of the canvas.

Example: Convert image on the left to the one on the right. (borders are not actual path but viewbox)

[image: Example]

Programming languages and tools does not matter. I just need something that I can apply to many files (in a bash script). So imagemagick, inkscape, python with thirdparty libs solutions are welcome.

Comment: how about adding sample SVG as code to test on ... I Think you have to add transform matrix on the parrent `<g>` object to translate and repair scale properly but that is just my first taught without any proof or trial ... Also is the `width` and `height` defined too (usually near the `viewBox`)?

Comment: @Spektre And the question is how ...

Comment: constructing [homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) is easy and you need just the 2D 3x3 version containing scaling and translation. But without sample SVG for testing and clarification on viewport I am not putting effort to answer.

Comment: I added answer looks like matrices are not needed at all for this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Playing with your test svg (using internet explorer as viewer) reveals that changing `viewBox` for SVG without defined `width,height` does not change their aspect (no stretching just zoom and pan) so no need to use matrices all can be done in `viewBox` alone. Here your example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
 <path d="M436 160c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20V48c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v416c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h320c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48v-48h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20zm-74 304H54a6 6 0 0 1-6-6V54a6 6 0 0 1 6-6h308a6 6 0 0 1 6 6v404a6 6 0 0 1-6 6zM128 208c0-44.183 35.817-80 80-80s80 35.817 80 80-35.817 80-80 80-80-35.817-80-80zm208 133.477V360c0 13.255-10.745 24-24 24H104c-13.255 0-24-10.745-24-24v-18.523c0-22.026 14.99-41.225 36.358-46.567l35.657-8.914c29.101 20.932 74.509 26.945 111.97 0l35.657 8.914C321.01 300.252 336 319.452 336 341.477z"/>
</svg>
```

so you want to change `448` to `512` but we want to still make the image centered so we need to adjust the x0 position too (in opposite direction by half of difference `(512-448)/2 = 32`). So change the `viewBox` to:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-32 0 512 512">
 <path d="M436 160c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20V48c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48H48C21.49 0 0 21.49 0 48v416c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h320c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48v-48h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-40c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12h-20v-64h20zm-74 304H54a6 6 0 0 1-6-6V54a6 6 0 0 1 6-6h308a6 6 0 0 1 6 6v404a6 6 0 0 1-6 6zM128 208c0-44.183 35.817-80 80-80s80 35.817 80 80-35.817 80-80 80-80-35.817-80-80zm208 133.477V360c0 13.255-10.745 24-24 24H104c-13.255 0-24-10.745-24-24v-18.523c0-22.026 14.99-41.225 36.358-46.567l35.657-8.914c29.101 20.932 74.509 26.945 111.97 0l35.657 8.914C321.01 300.252 336 319.452 336 341.477z"/>
</svg>
```

[image: preview]

so let assume original parameters are: `viewBox(x0,y0,xs0,ys0)` then the new ones would be `viewBox(x1,y1,xs1,ys1)` where:

```
xs1= ys1 = max(xs0,ys0);
x1 = x0 + (xs0 - xs1)/2;
y1 = y0 + (ys0 - ys1)/2;
```

As **SVG** is just text file (**XML**) in case you do not have **R/W** access to `SVG::viewBox` in your environment then just write a script that search/parse/replace `viewBox` text in text file ... I do not code in python but in **C++** would be just "few" lines of code (beware some **SVG**'s are **ASCII** some are **UNICODE**).

Answer (score 2):

If using ImageMagick 7, you can do the following:

```
magick -density X -colorspace sRGB file.svg -background white -gravity center -extent "%[fx:max(w,h)]x%[fx:max(w,h)]" result.png
```

If using ImageMagick 6, you need to compute the max size first, so

```
maxsize=$(convert -density X -colorspace sRGB file.svg format "%[fx:max(w,h)]" info:)
convert -density X -colorspace sRGB file.svg -background white -gravity center -extent ${max_size}x${max_size} result.png
```

This will not enlarge any bounding box lines, only the image.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but the thing is I'm going to need the SVG version of this (:

Comment: `@srush-r`. Sorry I do not know what you mean by the SVG version of my command. You likely can edit the SVG file to make the viewport square. But I suspect that would mean programming to read and edit and save the SVG file.

Comment: That is true. I need a square viewport that can be achieved by changing a single number in header. But there is more (that makes the problem hard for me) : The contents of SVG image need to move to the centre after vewport size is changed.

Comment: this gives me a white png image (ImageMagick 7.0.10-27)